# Upload different files through ckeditor

Tags: pdf, ckeditor, exe

I have checked http://ckeditor.com/demo#full.

But I can not find any option to upload .exe file through ckeditor.

Can I upload .exe file through this editor. If yes, how can I do this?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 7):

Use **Link** button, select **Upload** tab, select your file, upload it by pressing **Send it to server** button. If upload fails, than there is server side filter, and you cannot upload files with these extensions.

Comment: I have tried this, but I got an error "Invalid file extension"

Comment: than you cannot upload executable files, are you trying to upload some exploit? if you need just upload file, archive it in zip or 7z.

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.net 
You can Add Extension in config.ascx in CKFinder Folder.
i have the Same Problem as Mention Above
and i Have Solved my Problem by Adding File Extension in This File.
My Code in this File is

DefaultResourceTypes = "";

```
    ResourceType type;

    type = ResourceType.Add( "Files" );
    type.Url = BaseUrl + "files/";
    type.Dir = BaseDir == "" ? "" : BaseDir + "files/";
    type.MaxSize = 0;
    type.AllowedExtensions = new string[] { "7z", "aiff", "asf", "avi", "bmp", "csv", "doc", "docx", "fla", "flv", "gif", "gz", "gzip", "jpeg", "jpg", "mid", "mov", "mp3", "mp4", "mpc", "mpeg", "mpg", "ods", "odt", "pdf", "png", "ppt", "pptx", "pxd", "qt", "ram", "rar", "rm", "rmi", "rmvb", "rtf", "sdc", "sitd", "swf", "sxc", "sxw", "tar", "tgz", "tif", "tiff", "txt", "vsd", "wav", "wma", "wmv", "xls", "xlsx", "zip","inp","html" };
    type.DeniedExtensions = new string[] { };

    type = ResourceType.Add( "Images" );
    type.Url = BaseUrl + "images/";
    type.Dir = BaseDir == "" ? "" : BaseDir + "images/";
    type.MaxSize = 0;
    type.AllowedExtensions = new string[] { "bmp", "gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png" };
    type.DeniedExtensions = new string[] { };

    type = ResourceType.Add( "Flash" );
    type.Url = BaseUrl + "flash/";
    type.Dir = BaseDir == "" ? "" : BaseDir + "flash/";
    type.MaxSize = 0;
    type.AllowedExtensions = new string[] { "swf", "flv", "mp4" , "mp3"};
    type.DeniedExtensions = new string[] { };
```

Best Of Luck Its Working...